# vim-snipmate and supertab together

Tags: vim

i just tried to install snipmate. supertab is already working.

it doesnt work. when i press tab even after a snippet keyword the completion is triggered.
i tried to remap the key (to c-m) but even then completion is triggered instaed of snipmate. (before the remap c-m didnt do a thing).

i did this mapping in vimrc. the doc tells me to do it in after/plugin/snipmate.vim but this  script isnt loaded (according to :scriptnames).

any idea?

Answer (score 21):

snipmate plugin hasn't been updated for a long long time. thats why i started a friendly fork and i'm merging and coordinating further development of this (at least for me) essential plugin.

more here: https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem running an old version of snipmate from vim.org

The guy who writes it doesn't always update the vim.org page, but he does work on it fairly regularly on github.

Grab the latest copy from the download link [here](http://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/tree/master) and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

What did you remap to `<C-m>`? `<Tab>` or your plugins function calls? Did you try SnipMate without SuperTab?

Both plugins have their main functions hardwired to `<Tab>` which makes their use a bit unpredictable. I've tried it but I didn't like it.

Instead, maybe you can keep SnipMate (if it works on its own) and remap omnicompletion shortcuts to something easier. I have these in my .vimrc:

```
" change the mapleader from \ to ,
let mapleader=","

" omnicompletion : words
inoremap <leader>, <C-x><C-o>

" omnicompletion : filenames
inoremap <leader>: <C-x><C-f>

" omnicompletion : lines
inoremap <leader>= <C-x><C-l>
```

Also [autocomplpop.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879&rating=life_changing) works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Use SuperTab 2.0 version.

Do not use the latest version 2.1, it doesn't work with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remap SnippMate's TAB key to a different key, in my case c-j, and it worked OK:

```
ino <silent> <c-j><c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>
snor <silent> <c-j> <esc>i<right><c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>
```

I did the change in `after/plugin/snipmate.vim`. In my case, *:scriptnames* listed the file as loaded.

Answer (score 0):

add it to .vimrc, when you use Tab, then show the list of snippets.

`au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set expandtab
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sh set expandtab
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set expandtab`